# How to move several images to one position, then back to their original positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build a card matching game for a class I'm in, and I'm having a lot of trouble moving the cards around as I'd like them to.  The images are set up in a grid.  I'd like them to all move to the center, shuffle a few times, then go back to their original positions.  I'm able to get them to go to the center and shuffle, but when I tell them to return to their spots, they travel about 5 times further and overshoot their original spaces.  What am I doing wrong?

My images are arranged:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container"><img id="1"></div>
    <div class="container"><img id="2"></div>
    <div class="container"><img id="3"></div>
    <div class="container"><img id="4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="container"><img id="5"></div>
    <div class="container"><img id="6"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="container"><img id="7"></div>
    <div class="container"><img id="8"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="container"><img id="9"></div>
    <div class="container"><img id="10"></div>
    <div class="container"><img id="11"></div>
    <div class="container"><img id="12"></div>
</div>
```

The image sources are set later through js. The pertinent css is like this:

```
img{
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    position:relative;
}

.container{
    height:150px;
    width:180px;
    margin:0 2em;
}

.row{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 5em 0 0 0;
```

And the jquery that's supposed to move them around is this:

```
$('img').each(function(index){
    positions[index]=$(this).offset()
})

middle=$('.middle').offset()

$('img').each(function(index){
    left=middle.left-positions[index].left-75
    top=middle.top-positions[index].top
    $(this).animate({
        left: left,
        top: top
    },600)
})

for(i=0;i<5;++i){
    $('img').each(function(index){
        if(index<6){
            $(this).animate({
                left:'-=150',
            },150).animate({
                left:'+=150'
            },150)
        }
        else{
            $(this).animate({
                left:'+=150',
            },150).animate({
                left:'-=150'
            },150)
        }
    })
}

var delay=0

$('img').each(function(index){
    left=middle.left-positions[index].left-75
    top=middle.top-positions[index].top
    $(this).delay(delay).animate({
        left: left*-1,
        top: top*-1
    },600)
    delay+=100
})
```

If I multiply the top and left variables on the return by like -.15 instead of -1 I can get them back to close to their original positions, but as I run the game multiple times the differences add up and get out of control.  Sorry for the long code wall, thanks for any help.

Comment: I try to run your code. But it throws error

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking into it. It might be because it's a small selection of the code. You can find the full thing here: https://github.com/mabatemarco/matching. Thanks for any help!